# How to keep a String in a file after it is scanned in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Java program, which sorts different types of bikes according to prices. To do this, I have a file with two different types of bikes: mountain bikes and racing bikes. They both can be either green or blue. It has the following format:

```
Blue Racing:
Price: 300
Topspeed: 50
Green Mountain:
price: 400
Topspeed: 30
Blue Mountain:
Price: 150
Topspeed: 20
Green Racing:
Topspeed: 50
price: 750
```

Do sort these bikes, I made a parent class "Bike", with a subclass "RaceBike" and a subclass "MountainBike". This class has a scanning method. This method scans the type of bike and calls the scanning method of one of the subclasses, according to which type of bike is scanned.

All of the scanner methods have to look like this:

```
public static Bike scanner(Scanner scan);
```

However, as soon as, for example, "Blue Racing" is scanned in the parent class, these words cannot be accesed anymore by the Scanner in the scanner method of the subclass, but this is necessary to determine the color of the new Bike.

So my question is, how can I still access a word in a file, after I have scanned it?

Unfortunately, due to my college rules, I can't show any code. However, I can write some pseudocode to make it slightly more clear:

```
public static Bike scanner(Scanner scan){
     scan first word;
     scan second word;
     if second word equals racing
         return racingbike.scanner(scan)
     else
         return mountainbike.scanner(scan)
}

public static RacingBike scanner(Scanner scan){
     String color = scan first word //The color
     scan second word //kind of bike
     scan third word
     int price = scan first number // price
     return a new Racingbike, with attributes color and price
}
```

Implementing it like the above example is not possible, as the color can't be accesed in the RacingBike scanner method anymore. So I have to find a way to be able to still access it.

I can't change the return types and arguments of the methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass the scanner to a factory method (or a constructor), because it couples the *way* you get the values to the *user* of the values.

Write code to parse the file and deal with the order and type of values that are in the file. Keep it well away from anything that uses the Strings and ints parsed from the file.

By passing Strings and ints (and possibly enums) to the constructors, you make testing much easier, and you should write lots of unit tests.

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing (If I understand what you mean): for example, to get the price I do: int price = scan.nextInt(). Etc. I thought this was clear, but I will edit it now in my original question.

Comment: @JasonMacville no, you're not (I meant to say *factory method* instead of *constructor*). Let's put it this way: there should not be a class that uses/imports both RacingBike and Scanner.